# Floor function in t-time transition matrix (Markov Process)

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

In my math stats module, we are looking at stochastic processes. I am struggling with the Markov Processes chapter, specifically the section deriving Kolmogorov's forward and backward differential equations. In our notes, the matrix of time-t transition probabilities is written as **P**(t) = $\lfloor$p<sub>ij</sub>(t)$\rfloor$. Where p<sub>ij</sub>(t) is the probability of moving from state i to j in time t. Doesn't this mean that all of the values in the matrix will be 1 and 0? 
If so, why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

No each probabilities need to be between zero and 1. Though they all need to sum to one.